# JavaScript DOM Animation Border Color

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I have a small problem about editing the border color of an animation.

I tried using

```
document.getElementById("ID").style.animationName = "YellowBorder";
```

And I declared YellowBorder as :

```
<style>
YellowBorder {
   @keyframes animate-border {
                              0% {border-color: #000000;}
                              100% {border-color: #FFFF00;}
                             }
             }
</style>
```

I know this is wrong and for it to work it should be:

```
    <style>
   @keyframes animate-border {
                              0% {border-color: #000000;}
                              100% {border-color: #FFFF00;}
                             }
   </style>
```

But if I do this, it'll just become yellow before using any JavaScript code even if I put it on a

```
<script> If (condition) { <style> **HERE** </style> } </script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Border animation Keyframes/CSS Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50482132/border-animation-keyframes-css-animation)

Comment: Not really, they're not using any Javascript code. Just simple CSS Hover.

Comment: The keyframe definition is what you should focus on - that answer shows you very directly how to accomplish your goal and answers your question. Whether it is initiated via JavaScript or a CSS hover pseudo class is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

So i found an answer using a bit of my knowledge :
I had to create the style as a Javascript variable.

```
var Yellow = "@keyframes animate-border{ 0%{border-color: #000000;} 100%{border-color: #FFFF00;} }";
```

and then create a Style element :

```
var s = document.createElement("style");
```

Now we want that style to contain our "Yellow" inside it:

```
s.innerHTML = Yellow;
```

and Finally using this command to apply the style inside our web page :

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
```

Comment: You didn't have to do any of that. Just create another `@keyframes` with a different name and change the name of the animation via JavaScript. You were on the right track in your original post, you just had the wrong syntax; just replace `animate-border` with `YellowFrame`

Comment: I know there is an easy way to do it, and with using the past code. But so far i'm really comfortable with using it my way because i understand exactly what i am doing. But thank you for the suggestion.I might consider it in the future.